# Gulp v3.8.8 will not concat controller folder

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I want to exclude controller dir from my js folder and keep the controller files js on the same condition in dist folder.

Example :

```
js/controller/order/controller.js

js/controller/item/controller.js
```

So when i build the project, it should be in the `dist` folder with same structure, but not a single js file.

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src('./styles')
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});
```

Comment: Unclear, should it be gulp.src('./js') and not gulp.src('./styles')??  Secondly, you want to exclude the "controller" directory from this 'js' task?  What do you want to happen with the js/controller js files?

Comment: Sorry that was mistake . I want to copy the exact file to the dist folder.not like concat to a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude your controller folder with the negated blob:

```
# example structure 
src
 |--gulpfile.js
 |
 |--include
 |    |-- index.js
 |    `-- another.js
 |
 `--exclude
      `-- exclude.js
```

then in your gulp file:

```
#gulpfile.js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const merge = require('merge-stream');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('js', function() {
  const copy = gulp.src('./src/exclude/**/*.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))

  const build = gulp.src(['./src/**/*.js', '!./src/exclude/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('concat.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))

  return merge(copy, build);
});
```

Or if you don't want them to be in a single task:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('concatJs', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./src/**/*.js', '!./src/exclude/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('concat.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
});

gulp.task('copyJs', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/exclude/**/*.js')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
})

gulp.task('js', ['concatJs', 'copyJs']);
```

Result:

```
dist
  `--js
      |--concat.js
      `--exclude.js
```

Comment: i don't want concat to a single file. i want them to their separate folder as it is defined in src/js folder.

Comment: @boycod3 the excluded folder is not concat together with other js files at all. If you’d like to keep the same structure as in your src folder, you can edit the gulp.dist() of each tasks

Comment: your solution solves the problem. But in browser console sources. it is still in concat js file, not a separate js file.

Comment: @boycod3 hhhm, have you tried to clear your `./dist` folder before rebuilding? I have a example repo set up & the concat doesn't include the excluded folder.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude controllers from your concat task with regex. You can write another task to copy controllers to dist folder.

For more info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-copy

Of course you can use regex, and if you want to pimp your tasks use `gulp.parallel` where it is possible.

Comment: He's using v3.8.8 so gulp.parallel is not available.